# Can someone tell what's wrong in this python code?

Tags: python

Code:

```py
housePrice = input("What's the price of House? ")
is_goodCredit = input("Does buyer have good credit? ")

if is_goodCredit:
    downPayment = 0.1 * float(housePrice)
else:
    downPayment = 0.2 * float(housePrice)
    
print(f"Down payment will be {downPayment}")
```

The VS Code terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\bandh> & C:/Users/bandh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/bandh/Desktop/Untitled-1.py
What's the price of House? 1000
Does buyer have good credit? true
Down payment will be 100.0
PS C:\Users\bandh> & C:/Users/bandh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/bandh/Desktop/Untitled-1.py
What's the price of House? 1000
Does buyer have good credit? false
Down payment will be 100.0
```

As you can see when entering "false" the answer should have been 200 but it is showing 100. Why?

Answer (score 2):

```
is_goodCredit = input("Does buyer have good credit? ")
```

`is_goodCredit` returns a string. A string, as a condition, is seen as `True` if the string is not empty. Entering 'false', is seen as True. What you would want to check is whether the string matches 'false', such that:

```
if is_goodCredit == 'false':
```